# bind fails to resolve FQDN from root hints file

Tags: bind, dig

I'm trying to re-lean how to set up a bind named server after many years. I set up a simulated local LAN and ISP using GNS3. I have an internal and external view for DNS. no errors in zone configuration as verified named-checkzone plus no errors in logs

I can't resolve any domain name outside the local zone. on a test box in local zone I tried:

```
$ dig +trace ns1.comp2.org

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> +trace ns1.comp2.org
;; global options: +cmd
.                       3600000 IN      NS      ns1.isp1.org.
.                       3600000 IN      NS      ns1.isp2.org.
couldn't get address for 'ns1.isp1.org': failure
couldn't get address for 'ns1.isp2.org': failure
dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.isp1.org': no more
```

root hints file (copied the format of the original file, I don't quite know how this is supposed to be formatted):

```
. 3600000 IN NS ns1.isp1.org.
ns1.isp1.org. 3600000 A 1.0.0.14
. 3600000 IN NS ns1.isp2.org.
ns1.isp2.org. 3600000 A 2.0.0.14
```

since this is debian named.conf is split into various files.

named.conf:

```
//... (logging)

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
//include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

and named.conf.default-zones:

```
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/var/bind/db.root";
};
...
```

named.conf.options:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        ...
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

named.conf.local:

```
view "internal" {
    match-clients { 192.168.1.0/24; };
    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
    recursion yes;
    zone "comp1-internal" {
        type master;
        file "/var/bind/db.comp1-internal";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
    zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/bind/db.1.168.192";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
};
view "external" {
    match-clients { "any"; };
    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
    recursion yes;
    zone "comp1.org" {
        type master;
        file "/var/bind/db.comp1.org";
    };
    zone "16-31.0.0.1.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/var/bind/db.16-31.0.0.1";
        allow-update { none; };
    };
    zone "16-31.0.0.2.in-addr.arpa" {
        type slave;
        file "/var/bind/db.16-31.0.0.2";
        masters { 2.0.0.17; };
    };
};
```

I assume this is correct since the fact dig +trace shows returns some data from the root hints file means it appears to attempt a recursive search, but then gives up without reading the A record right in the roots file. I'm still looking through the log file for clues. I'm not currently using DNSSEC. could this be the issue?